# How to use awk to match all non-private range IP addresses in log file?

Tags: regex, awk, grep, ip

I want to match ( and count their number of occurrence ) all the non-private range IP addresses from a mail log and I'm failing miserably.

From what I know:

- it should match 4x3 digits pattern, since it's an IP address, excluding:

  - `10\.`
  - `192\.168\.`
  - `172\.1[6789]\.`
  - `172\.2[0-9]\.`
  - `172\.3[01]\.`
  - `127\.0\.0\.1`

[1] example: a postfix mail log line looks like this:

`CONNECT from [217.113.54.21]:56590 to [192.168.1.100]:25`

whereas the first match is a valid, external IP and that is what I need.

Anyone with the knowledge around?

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to get you going:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/\[([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}\]/) ) {
        ip = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)

        if ( ip ~ /^(\
10\.|\
192\.168\.|\
172\.1[6789]\.|\
172\.2[0-9]\.|\
172\.3[01]\.|\
127\.0\.0\.1)/ ) {
            invalid[ip]++
        }
        else {
            valid[ip]++
        }
    }
}

END {
    print "Valid IPs found:"
    for (ip in valid) {
        print "\t" ip, valid[ip]
    }

    print "\nInvalid IPs found:"
    for (ip in invalid) {
        print "\t" ip, invalid[ip]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ cat file
CONNECT from [217.113.54.21]:56590 to [192.168.1.100]:25
CONNECT from [217.113.54.21]:56590 to [192.168.2.99]:25

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Valid IPs found:
        217.113.54.21 2

Invalid IPs found:
        192.168.1.100 1
        192.168.2.99 1
```

Without some more sample input and expected output in your question, there's not much more we could do to help you at this point.

Comment: In what way did it "not work for you"? Wrong output, no output, syntax error, core dump, what? What awk version are you using? Does it support RE intervals ({3})?

Comment: sorry for the short comment, I should have explained deeper.

The lists ended up empty and yes, the issues is with the {3} for the first 3x3 IP. match; I've tested it with explicitly adding [0-9]{1,3}\. three times instead.

Comment: OK then just make the recurrences explicit. I don't understand why {1,3} would work while {3} doesn't but if it works for your awk...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.

`awk 'match($3, /\[([0-9.]+)\]:[0-9]+/, arr){}; arr[1] !~ /^(192.168|10|172.16|127).[.0-9]+/ {print arr[1]}' file`

Comment: That's gawk-specific, the wrong syntax for a standalone action, will falsely match on various strings that are not IP addrs, will falsely identify some valid ip addrs as invalid, and will only operate on one field of each line instead of looking for all IPs on each line.

Comment: I understand that need only match "from [217.113.54.21]:56590". 
If ip is a reverse zone, the line will be skipped.
I can not post it test file and the result:(.

Answer (score 0):

Private IP ranges are

1. 10.0.0.0 — 10.255.255.255 ~ Class A
2. 172.16.0.0 — 172.31.255.255 ~ Class B
3. 192.168.0.0 — 192.168.255.255 ~ Class C
4. 127.0.0.0/8 ~ localhost

This single liner should help

```
cat File | awk '!/^(192.168|10|127).[.0-9]+/' | awk '!/^(172).[.16-31]+/' > PublicIP.txt ; wc -l PublicIP.txt
```

*This will create a file with all PublicIPs and show you how many total non-private IP are there*